# Webview could't download file from dynamic post URL in Android

Tags: android, webview, download, dynamic-url

I have web view which loads one website. On the page there is one button to download excel file. But when I click on that it only refreshing the page nothing download even I have set download listener too.

Download listener does't call on button click. But on other browser like Google chrome on mobile this functionality is working well.

I have added all the permission related it and I seen lot of similar questions on stack overflow and other place but nothing I have got.

Here is my web view code looks like:

```
void setupWebview(){

    webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webSettings = webview.getSettings();
    webSettings.setUserAgentString(newAgentString);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
    webSettings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    }
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webview.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient()); 
    webview.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, final String                                 mimeType,
                                    long contentLength) {

        Log.d("Erpp", "main onDownlaod : url : " + url);

    });

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webview,true);
    } else {
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can show code for your webview?

Comment: Hello, @MeosCoder  I have updated my question with webview code please see that. And thanks for your replay.

Comment: What is a `dynamic post URL`?

Comment: `On one page there is one button for download excel file. `. Please show the html code.

Comment: `Please show the html code.`. And or the javascript.

Comment: @greenapps `Please show the html code.`  The `export button` is a standard `HTML submit` button, which submit's the `parent form` on click. There is `no javascript used` for this.
The contents are gathered at `server side`, converted in `excel format` and send the content with attachment header.

Comment: @greenapps - `This is header`  : **Content-Type** (it is based on type of excel file like for xls it is application/vnd.ms-excel)
**Content-Disposition**: attachment;filename=<name of the file>
**Cache-Control:** max-age=0

Comment: `On one page there is one button for download excel file. `. No. To submit/post a form.

Comment: `But Download listener does't call on click. `. Why would it? You are posting a form.

Comment: I still wonder what you mean with dynamic post URL.

Comment: @greenapps `Why would it? You are posting a form. ` for download the file which has the header  in response header. I have told you above like that.

Comment: @greenapps Still I am facing this problem please give some suggetions if you know about. And please forgot `dynamic post URL` I was just guessing this.